# I have a strange circle aroung my spiderweb, how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, grafana

I created a Spiderweb in Highcharts but i have the problem, that around the Spiderweb is a circle. But i don´t want to have it. The second thing is, that i want to rotate the complete SPiderweb for 30 degrees, but i don´t know how..

```
{
   "title":{
      "text":"",
      "style":{
         "fontSize":10,
         "fontFamily":"Arial"
      }
   },
   "chart":{
      "inverted":false,
     "alignTicks":false,
      "polar":true,
      "type":"line",
      "style": {
            "fontFamily": "Arial",
        },
      "annotations":[{
        "shapes":[{
          "strokeWidth":"0px",
        }]
      }]  
   },

   "xAxis":{
      "categories":["Power","O2", "AR","LOX","LIN","LAR"],
      "tickmarkPlacement":"on",
      "startOnTick":true,
      "labels":{
         "enabled":true,
         "fontFamily":"Arial",
         "startAngle":0
      }
   },
   "yAxis":{
      "gridLineInterpolation":"polygon",
      "lineWidth":0,
      "min":-10,
      "max":10,
      "tickInterval":5,
      "title":{
         "text":"",
         "style":{
            "fontSize":12,
            "fontFamily":"Arial"
         }
      },
      "plotOptions":{
        "series":{
          "LineWidth":0,
          "pointStart":0,
          "pointInterval":"interval" 
        }
      },
      "tooltip":{
        "shared":true,
        "pointFormat":"<span style='color:{series.color}'>{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>"
      },
      "labels":{
         "style":{
            "fontSize":12,
            "fontFamily":"Arial"
         }
      }
   },
      "series":{
         "enableMouseTracking":false,
         "dataLabels":{
            "enabled":true
         }
      },
   "legend":{
      "enabled":true,
      "backgroundColor":"transparent",
      "itemStyle":{
         "fontSize":12,
         "fontWeight":"normal",
         "fontFamily":"Arial",
      }
   },
   "responsive":{
     "rules":[{
       "condition":{
         "maxWidth":500
       },
       "chartOptions":{
         "legend":{
           "align":"center",
           "verticalAlign":"bottom",
           "layout":"horizontal"
         },
         "pane":{
           "size":"70%"
         }
       }
     }]
   },
   "credits":{
      "text":"© ROT"
   }
}
```

That´s my Code for the Spiderweb. 
PS: The series are in a extra box..(not relevant for my question)

Comment: add " linewidth: 0 " param to xAxis that wil remove your circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle around your SpiderWeb can be removed please replace below:

```
 xAxis: {
   categories:["Power","O2", "AR","LOX","LIN","LAR"],
   tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
   startOnTick:true,
   labels:{
     enabled:true,
     fontFamily:"Arial",
     startAngle:0
   },
   lineWidth: 0
 },
```

Unfortunately, Highcharts doesn't have a "rotation" option implemented. For this moment you can only play with CSS rotation:

```
#container {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: How to use this "transform" in my Code?

Comment: Hi @BS1010, container is the id of my main div i.e parent div for which I am applying highchart, you can use yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the circle by setting `xAxis.lineWidth` to 0. To rotate the chart use `startAngle` property:

```
pane: {
    ...,
    startAngle: 30
},

xAxis: {
    ...,
    lineWidth: 0
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ujyt123/1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.lineWidth

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane.startAngle